# How to allow clients write to a variable?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

I have a functionality that allows each connected players in a multiplayer network to go to the next player after finishing your turn. The problem is that it only works for the host/server but not the client.

I get the following error

```
InvalidOperationException: Client is not allowed to write to this NetworkVariable
```

The network variable specified above is this one here:

```
currentPlayerIndex.Value = nextPlayerIndex;

currentPlayerID.Value = allPlayerIDs[nextPlayerIndex];
```

They are found in the nextturn method highlighted below.

This is what my code does:

1. The Player Manager has Network Behavior inherited that allows synchronization of all connected players and current player. It has the next turn method

```
   public void NextTurn()
    {
        int nextPlayerIndex = (currentPlayerIndex.Value + 1) % allPlayerIDs.Count;
        currentPlayerIndex.Value = nextPlayerIndex;

        currentPlayerID.Value = allPlayerIDs[nextPlayerIndex];

        Debug.Log("Next Turn : " + currentPlayerID.Value);
    }
```

2. The Player Controller (also inherits Network Behavior) is a script instantiated alongside the player when starting a client or host. It checks if it is your turn to allow the button to set active so that the client can click and allow next turn to be called.

```
private NetworkVariable<bool> isMyTurn = new NetworkVariable<bool>(false, NetworkVariableReadPermission.Everyone, NetworkVariableWritePermission.Owner);
public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        PlayerManager.Instance.shootBtn.onClick.AddListener(() => PlayerManager.Instance.NextTurn());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        spriteRenderer.enabled = isMyTurn.Value;

        if (!IsOwner) return;

        Debug.Log("Current Player ID : " + currentPlayerID.Value + " : Current Player Index : " + currentPlayerIndex.Value);

        if (OwnerClientId != PlayerManager.Instance.GetCurrentPlayerID())
        {
            isMyTurn.Value = false;
        }
        else if (OwnerClientId == PlayerManager.Instance.GetCurrentPlayerID())
        {
            isMyTurn.Value = true;
        }

        Debug.Log("CurrentPlayer : " + PlayerManager.Instance.GetCurrentPlayerID());

        // Active to only the current Player
        PlayerManager.Instance.shootBtn.interactable = isMyTurn.Value;
    }
```

1. I tried to use Client RPC methods that are called from the server to allow the changes to cut across all clients but still it brings the above error.
2. I also tried to change the write permissions of the following variables in PlayerManager to **Server** but still the issue remains:

```
private NetworkVariable<int> currentPlayerIndex = new NetworkVariable<int>(0, NetworkVariableReadPermission.Everyone, NetworkVariableWritePermission.Owner);

    private NetworkVariable<ulong> currentPlayerID = new NetworkVariable<ulong>(0, NetworkVariableReadPermission.Everyone, NetworkVariableWritePermission.Owner);
```

The write permissions are only 2 : Owner and Server.

What could be the best solution to allow the client to also update the next turn?

Comment: a serverrpc call who can update the variable?